# React Native - setState to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to change some layout in `Header` when `Home` is started. So I decide to call the `setState` when `Home` `componentWillMount`. How can I setState to other component in different js file.

Header.js

```
    class Header extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { type: '' };
        }

        render() {
            if(this.state.type == "home"){
                //do something
            }else{
                //do something
            }
         }
    }

    module.exports = Header;
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => Header);
```

Home.js

```
    class Home extends React.Component {

        //set from here
        componentWillMount(){
            this.setState({Header.state.type:'home'});
        }
    }

    module.exports = Home;
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => Home);
```

Comment: You should use a common parent component which gets mounted to `registerComponent()` and renders both Home and Header.

Comment: @xDreamCoding hi thanks for reply. sorry I very new in react-native, what is common parent component? can show me a example . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need one common parent component and only one initial component mounting via `AppRegistry.registerComponent()`. Like so:

Parent.js

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { type: '' };
    }

    render() {
        <Header></Header>
        <Home></Home>
     }
}

module.exports = Parent;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => Parent);
```

The `AppRegistry.registerComponent();` calls in your other components need to be removed.

Comment: is there another way to do this ? because i using `StackNavigator`, so there are no parent component